# iOSでGoogleタスクAPIを使いたい

Tags: ios, xcode

以下のGoogleのサンプルを参考にプログラミングを行っています。
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/quickstart/ios?ver=objc

しかしbuild時に以下のエラーが出てしまい、buildを完了することが出来ません。

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLQueryTasks", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in TRGoogleOAuthViewController.o
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLServiceTasks", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in TRGoogleOAuthViewController.o
>     "_kGTLAuthScopeTasksReadonly", referenced from:
>         -[TRGoogleOAuthViewController createAuthController] in TRGoogleOAuthViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

開発環境は以下のとおりとなります
Xcode : 7.0
deployment target 9.0
OSX : 10.10.5

設定等で見直すべき部分等ありますでしょうか。
お分かりになりましたら回答方法をご教授ください。